# Syntax highlighting is wrong

Tags: support, specific-question, syntax-highlighting

I've create a question here [Higher order function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677391/higher-order-function-name) with javascript code but it seems it show lisp syntax (I have lisp tag). I've try to include:

```
 <!-- language: javascript -->
```

But stil got lisp syntax. What's wrong here?

Comment: See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two language tags, the default is to use language heuristics instead.

You picked a non-standard language tag; you need to use one listed on [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) instead. `lang-js` works, `javascript` does not.

I edited your post to use the `language-all` feature to mark all blocks as JavaScript:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-js -->
```

Comment: `javascript` means [javascript] tag, `lang-javascript` or `lang-js` means the actual language. `language-all` just makes life easier.

Comment: @Antony: but the `javascript` tag in the `language` comment *is not supported*.

Comment: I know. I am just pointing out the significance of `lang-` here, which is the main reason behind this syntax highlighting issue. Without it, it means the tag instead of the language. It just happens that the javascript tag is not supported, according to the answer you linked.